# SUM of 1 or more fields using GROUP BY

Tags: visualforce, group-by

I have got a situation where there is a filed named "Sub-Category" which is dependent on its master "Category", 3 check boxes and a formula field. So, when I select a "Category" (for ex. X), then a "Sub-Category" (for ex. Y) and then check a check-box. Doing so, a formula field will say as "Available Count: 1" , because, I have checked a single check box. Similarly, if I create another record with Category as X, Sub-Category as Z and check 2 check boxes, then the "Available Count will be 2".

Now, I am supposed to display the "Available Count" in the VF page along side its "Sub Category" grouped under their respective "Category".

For which, I have written the following query

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT Category__c, SUM(Available_Spots__c)totalAvailable
                                    FROM FAQ_Advertising_Inventory__c
                                    GROUP BY Category__c
                                    ];

    for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  
    {
        System.debug('Category List' + ar.get('Category__c'));                        
        System.debug('Total Available' + ar.get('totalAvailable'));
    }
```

I had written this query in the Constructor.

And I am getting the right values (Category List & Total Available) when I debug the above ones. However, I also need to get the Subcategory grouped under Category, which I am unable to do so & I need to know how to display the result of the above query on VF page.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're looking for another field to get from your grouping... in order to achieve this you just group all the fields you are querying independently in order to receive this information.

`SELECT Category__c, SubCategory__c, SUM(Available_Spots__c)totalAvailable
       FROM FAQ_Advertising_Inventory__c
       GROUP BY Category__c, SubCategory__c`

To display this information within Salesforce lets say you return `groupedResults` you'll access the values when looping through it with something like this:

`<apex:repeat value="{!groupedResults}" var="gr">
     {!gr['Category__c']} has a count of {!gr['totalAvailable']}
</apex:repeat>`

Lastly if you are looking at getting records with a a sum of at least 1, use the `HAVING` clause as shown here [Salesforce Doc for HAVING](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm|SkinName=webhelp)

`SELECT Category__c, SUM(Available_Spots__c)totalAvailable
       FROM FAQ_Advertising_Inventory__c
       GROUP BY Category__c HAVING SUM(Available_Spots__c) > 1`